Where to import packages when using ProcessPoolExecutor in subfunctions
I have a code structure in which there is a main function (‘main’). In this main function, a function (‘coordinate’) is called in parallel with ProcessPoolExecutor. This ‘coordinate’ calls many other functions (‘subs’), which are located in different files. In each file, all the packages required for the ‘subs’ are imported at the beginning.
If I execute ‘coordinate’ serially, no error occurs. However, when I switch to parallel execution, for example, the error ‘Error: cannot access local variable “pickle” where it is not associated with a value’ occurs. I have read that with parallel function calls I have to write the packages to be imported into the function and not at the beginning of the files. Does this also apply to the ‘subs’? So I have to write the packages that need to be imported in each ‘subs’ and not at the beginning of the file that contains the ‘sub’? Or is there a more elegant way? I mean, if a ‘sub’ is called several times, the packages are also imported several times.
Thanks in advance.
